# Binary XGCD for polynomials

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math, greatest-common-divisor, boolean-polynomials

There exists a [binary GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) for finding the greatest common divisor of a number.  In general, the GCD can be extended to the [XGCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which can help find a multiplicative inverse in a field.

I am working with binary numbers that represent a polynomial.  For example, the bitstring `1101` represents *x^3 + x^2 + 1*.  I need to compute the modular inverse of a random polynomial modulo *x^p - 1* for some large known prime *p*.  However, I need to do it in constant time (meaning that the runtime should not depend on the number I am inverting).  I know how to make the binary GCD constant time and I know how to implement the XGCD for polynomials in order to compute multiplicative inverses.  What I don't know is if there exists a binary GCD equivalent (with corresponding XGCD) for (binary) polynomials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. The "binary" GCD works in any ring where the smallest prime exists. For integers it is `2`, hence the name binary. For polynomials, it is `x`. The algorithm follows the same idea: subtract polynomials to eliminate a free term in one of higher degree, factor out the highest possible power of `x`, and keep going until the result of subtraction becomes zero.

Comment: That's cool, the factor _x_ is the same as the value 2 in the binary representation, which means that multiplication/division by _x_ is just bitshifting, just as it is when multiplying/dividing by 2. Also, "odd"/"even" can be determined by inspecting just the last bit. Also, addition is equal to subtraction (xor) and has no carries. All in all, I'd say this is going to be a fast algorithm.